# How to populate Spinner with Specific column of Room Database?

Tags: android, android-spinner, dao, android-room

in my app, I'm trying to fix a spinner which shows location details as a dropdown. The locations are stored in a column of Room database table. I'm not able to retrieve the single column of Strings and populate it in Spinner.

table-note;

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "locations")
    private String locations;
```

Dao:

```
  @Query("SELECT locations FROM `table-note`")
    List<String> getAllLocations();
```

main activity:

```
  final  List<String> locationList = noteDatabase.noteDao().getAllLocations();

 final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,R.layout.spinner_item,locationList){
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                if(position == 0)
                {

                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if(position == 0){

                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };

 spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: where is the problem ??

Comment: Have you removed *`*table-note*`*? Please remove quote then check it.

Comment: nope., not working